# How can I see executor logs in Livy running in kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, livy

I am having a stable/spark Helm deployment running on Kubernetes and submitting the job through Livy.

> curl -X POST --data '{"className": "LogBundleConfigFetcher",
>   "file": "http:///aliceparser_2.11-19.12.09.jar" ,"args": [""]}'
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://:8998/batches

I am able to see the driver logs in the Livy pod. But not able to see executor logs.

Is there any way I can see the executors log?

Comment: Did you try to see the logs from the other spark containers?

Comment: @rabello yes I tried to see logs of both the worker pods.. it didn't show anything

Answer (score 1):

Livy API doesn't provide a way to access Spark Executor logs.

I would recommend you to look at the [Grafana Loki project](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/) for easy logs collection in Kubernetes cluster.

Also Livy can be customized to collect Executor logs, but it'll be a great overhead on scale.

Comment: We are using Kibana but that is also showing only driver logs. Should I use spark-history server deployment to store the logs somewhere?

Comment: Spark History Server stores event logs only (the snapshot of the Spark UI, not the STDOUT). Concerning Kibana - the issue is in the way you collect the logs. Probably you need to add some additional configs to your Elastic/Kibana setup to collect executor logs, or check the query you use in Kibana. Unfortunately I don't have ELK setup by my hand, but I can share with you the Prometheus stack I use to monitor Spark Apps in Kubernetes: https://github.com/jahstreet/spark-on-kubernetes-helm/tree/master/charts/spark-monitoring. Hope it helps.